# Python PyQt6 QTableView column 0, row 0 highlighted on GUI load

Tags: python, pyqt6

I've noticed when loading a `QTableView` (I'm using a `QStandardItemModel`) with data, on load of the GUI, column 0, row 0 is highlighted (I have 4 columns, the first is hidden, rows vary).  The highlighted color is different than the color scheme for the table, and the color reacts to what is set by the selection color, though it is not the same as the selection color.  It's not a selection, though (`hasSelection()` returns false).  I swear I found a question dealing with this here back when I first started working on this project, but can't find it again (I was not looking to solve this "issue" at the time).

MRE:

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtGui


class GUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        data = [QtGui.QStandardItem('test'), QtGui.QStandardItem('test'), QtGui.QStandardItem('test')]
        self.model.appendRow(data)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
main_gui = GUI()
main_gui.show()
app.exec()
```

Screenie:

[image: thumbnail]

How can I disable this functionality?  I'd like the table to be a uniform color, based on my settings.  I've looked at every method in the docs, and it must be one of those "if it was a snake it would have bitten you" things, 'cause I can find nothing that has anything to do with highlighting an item on load.  Summary: how to disable the apparent default functionality of highlighting r0, c0 on load?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of what you're seeing, and possibly a basic [mre] to reproduce the issue. Also, what OS and version are you using.

Comment: Hey @musicamante.  Give me a few minutes and I'll whip up "throw away" code.  My project is an email client, and is using my primary email for testing, so for privacy reasons, I don't want to post a screenie of the actual GUI.  I can say that I am on Linux Nobara (Fedora based), but had this problem on Mint as well.  PyQt6 is version 6.3.1 (latest).

Comment: That seems the default hover effect. Do you have the mouse cursor there? What if you move it?

Comment: No, it's not a result of the mouse cursor, as it doesn't matter where the cursor is when I open the window; the above happens.  If I select something with the cursor (or keyboard), all is good with code not posted.  It's something with the view, and it's not easy to find within the docs.

Comment: The *visual* result depends on the *style*, not directly on the view. That could then be the hint about the current index. If that only interests you for the startup phase, then just do `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.view.setCurrentIndex(QtCore.QModelIndex()))`.

Comment: Solid, musicamante.  That line worked like a charm.  I guess that highlighting was indicating the current index.  I never figured that.  Thanks yet again.